# List index out of range from table exported from Excel

Tags: list, indexing, integer

I'm exporting a list of values from an excel, it goes something like this

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYTue.png)

There are 20 lines in total where in column a and b have some negative decimal values. Firstly I used `int()` for the exported data since I was getting the Float error because there are some decimals and with negative sign. After that when I try to run the code to read the list values it gives me the error list index out of range. What am I doing wrong?

```
# Load data
df = pd.read_excel("/Data ED.xlsx")
print(df)
datos = df.to_numpy().tolist()
print(len(datos))
Size=datos[0][0]
print(Size)
CapMax=datos[1][0]
print(CapMax)
Peso=np.zeros(int(Size))

for i in range(0,int(Size)):
  Peso[i]=datos[i+2][1]
   
print(Peso)
```